# Node.js - crypto.js - PFX header too long

Tags: javascript, node.js, https, pfx

I am trying to load in a PFX and passphrase from a file so that I can make a HTTPS request. Before I start, I already know that the PFX is good and that is not the issue.

I am doing the following:

```
config.options.pfx = fs.readFileSync('file.pfx');
config.options.passphrase = 'passphrase';
```

I am passing my options into an agent.

```
config.options.agent = new https.Agent(options);
```

I then try to build the rquest where I get the following error:

```
crypto.js:143
      c.context.loadPKCS12(pfx, passphrase);
            ^
Error: header too long
    at Object.exports.createCredentials (crypto.js:143:17)
    at Object.exports.connect (tls.js:1334:27)
    at Agent.createConnection (https.js:79:14)
    at Agent.createSocket (http.js:1293:16)
    at Agent.addRequest (http.js:1269:23)
    at new ClientRequest (http.js:1416:16)
    at Object.exports.request (https.js:123:10)
```

I checked this out from a work repository where I know that this works for the original author of it.  For some reason my set-up is not running it, though.

Comment: A hint: pfx is just a PKCS12 version bastardized by MS, so some crypto tools work with pfx while others - don't. try generating native PKCS12 or transform pfx to PKCS12 using openssl tool.

Comment: I got exactly the same problem with a valid PFX (PKCS12) file, with no solution. Have you solved it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I had a similar issue. It turned out I was using `fs.readFileSync('file.pfx', 'utf8')`, which is correct for PEM files, but since PKCS12 files are binary, you should just pass in `fs.readFileSync('file.pfx')`.

Comment: Thanks, that's really helped me!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but in my case i was using

```
pfx: fs.readFileSync('certs/keystore.p12')
```

In my case, the problem was that the pfx I was using was not correctly generated from the jks. Exporting with keytool was the right solution

```
keytool -v -importkeystore -srckeystore keystore.jks -destkeystore keystore.p12 -deststoretype PKCS12
```